# In MVC is it okay to handle data at all in the view?

Tags: model-view-controller

I currently have a method in my view which creates an object from user input and returns it to the controller where its called:

```
//In view class

myObject x = new myObject();
x.setAttribute1(TextField1.getText());
x.setAttribute3(TextField2.getText());
x.setAttribute3(TextField3.getText());
return x;
```

Does this violate the terms of MVC? Would it be more appropriate to create the object in the controller and use getter methods in the view to set its attributes:

```
//In controller class

myObject x = new myObject();
x.setAttribute1(myView.getTextField1().getText());
x.setAttribute2(myView.getTextField2().getText());
x.setAttribute3(myView.getTextField3().getText());
...
```

Comment: I think it's not right to put "generate"-code in a view. Maybe a Builder Class helps you here more

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is wrong.

The main problem, an absolute no-go, is to create the model in the view. Controllers create models, models may create associated models, but views definitely do not.

Views display models. That is what they do, nothing more, nothing less. Views also do not write the user input into models, they return user input in whatever format to the controller, which decides what to do.

If you are in a more classic form based GUI, that is, not a web application, the view still does not directly manipulate the model. Use an Observer pattern instead to decouple.